# Terraform: Error while creating CloudWatch alarm for multiple instances

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating multiple ec2 instances in two regions. I wanted to associate CloudWatch alarm for status checks and CPU utilization.

Below I have mentioned the directory structure and the code for cloudwatch and main.tf which is representing the calling of modules.

I am having 2 issues including the logic in the creation of cloudwatch alarms.

Directory Structure:

```
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── alb
│   │   ├── aws_alb.tf
│   │   ├── aws_instance.tf
│   │   ├── bootstrap.sh
│   │   ├── cloudwatch.tf
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── output.tf
│   │   ├── security-group.tf
│   │   ├── sns.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── route53
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── variables.tf
```

main.tf

```
module "north-virginia" {
  source          = "./modules/alb"
  region          = "us-east-1"
  az              = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
}

module "oregon" {
  source          = "./modules/alb"
  region          = "us-west-2"
  az              = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
}
```

modules/alb/aws_instance.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami               = "${data.aws_ami.amzn2.id}"
  instance_type     = "${var.instance_type}"
  count             = 3
  availability_zone = "${element(var.az, count.index)}"
  tags {
    Name = "${count.index}"
  }
}
```

modules/alb/cloudwatch.tf

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu_utilization" {
  count               = "${length(local.instance_id_var)}"
  alarm_name          = "${element(split(",", join(",", aws_instance.web.*.id)), count.index)}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "2"
  metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
  period              = "120"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "60"
  alarm_description   = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"

  dimensions {
    InstanceId = "${element(aws_instance.web.*.id, count.index)}"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "status_check" {
  count               = 3
  alarm_name          = "${element(split(",", join(",", aws_instance.web.*.id)), count.index)}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "2"
  metric_name         = "StatusCheckFailed"
  namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
  period              = "120"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "1"
  alarm_description   = "This metric monitors ec2 status check."

  dimensions {
    InstanceId = "${element(aws_instance.web.*.id, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Expected Behaviour: 
I want each instance should have above 2 alarms attached to it in each region.

Erroneous Behaviour:
It is creating and attaching 3 alarms in each region with instances.

- For North-Virginia region - One for CPU two for StatusCheck.
- For Oregon region - Two for StatusCheck and One for CPU Utilization.

Every time I apply It creates the alarms vice-versa.

I am getting below error which is resolved if I wait for 2 minutes while it is updating the alarm or if i use `terraform apply -parallelism=1`

Error:

```
4 error(s) occurred:

* module.north-virginia.aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.status_check[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.status_check.0: Creating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: A separate request to update this alarm is in progress.
status code: 400, request id: ea6c4502-dede-11e8-9262-c55251d6673a
* module.north-virginia.aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.cpu_utilization[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.cpu_utilization.1: Creating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: A separate request to update this alarm is in progress.
status code: 400, request id: ea6c6c09-dede-11e8-a13f-bbb86ff53045
* module.oregon.aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.status_check[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.status_check.1: Creating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: A separate request to update this alarm is in progress.
status code: 400, request id: ed198a56-dede-11e8-b95a-9d366b9f2e85
* module.oregon.aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.cpu_utilization[3]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.cpu_utilization.3: Creating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: A separate request to update this alarm is in progress.
status code: 400, request id: ed193c4d-dede-11e8-9c63-21cde1551122
```

Any Idea or any Convention which I am missing out here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would simplify your testing by removing/commenting out the `module "oregon"`. Once you get the *virginia* one right, then re-add it.

Second, I would switch the code in your module to calculate the counts as the length of the `var.az`. This should be for the 3 resources you have: aws_instance and the 2 CloudWatch alarms. e.g.:

```
count = "${length(var.az)}"
```

That way you can change the # of AZs in the code calling the module and dynamically alter the # of instances created.

Third, the `name` you're giving the CloudWatch alarms look to be the same. Try differentiating them. e.g.:

```
alarm_name = "${element(split(",", join(",", aws_instance.web.*.id)), count.index)}-cpu-util"
alarm_name = "${element(split(",", join(",", aws_instance.web.*.id)), count.index)}-status-check"
```

PS> between tests, make sure you've cleared out all resources that may have been created to ensure you're running a clean test.

Comment: Yes, The issue was with alarm_name.